# How to check if user has granted a certain set of permissions to my app, using the Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: permissions, facebook-c#-sdk

Just as the question states, how do I check if a user has granted a certain set of permissions to my app, using the Facebook C# SDK?

For example, the "user_groups" permissions? Particularly if they've already granted other permissions?

I have a certain part of my app that needs the extended permissions, and I'll need to request them from the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("accessToken");
dynamic result = fb.Get("/me/permissions");
```